# Does something like Common Table Expressions exist in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I recently learned about CTE's in SQL Server and am attempting to use it in PL/SQL.  I do not need the recurive benefits of it, however, I would like to use it in lieu of creating a view and to improve query performance.  Just looking for some direction on what code may be similar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Oracle this is known as subquery factoring, and it works the same as in SQL Server AFAIK:

```
with cte as (select * from emp)
select * from cte join dept on dept.deptno = cte.deptno;
```

See [SELECT documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702) and search for "factoring".

Comment: +1: Supported since 9i, Subquery factoring didn't support the recursive portion till 11g (which is now ANSI) because Oracle already supported hierarhical queries using CONNECT BY syntax...  I don't recall when PostgreSQL started supporting the syntax, likely in v8.x.  But CTEs/Subquery Factoring doesn't improve query performance, just different syntax for derived tables/inline views.

Comment: Many thanks. I am using Oracle 8i which would explain why I'm striking out.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: The recursive function of the `with` clause was not supported until 11g R2. (Not availabe in 11g R1.) See: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/wnsql.htm#sthref6